# AngularJS: cookies fail on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I used `$cookies` from `ngCookies` to store an array of objects, but when I refresh the browser the length of the data grows, and is no longer accessible as an array.

I searched online and found `cookieStore` still within `ngCookies` I used it and it works just fine, so I wonder, what could be wrong with `cookies`. Below are the codes I tried.

```
//Used this to in the run method to check if cookie exist
$rootScope.cart =  $cookies.get('cart') || []; 

//On button click I run the code below which fails after browser refresh
$rootScope.cart.push(response.data);
$cookies.put('cart', $rootScope.cart);
```

PS: I am a newbie in angularjs

Comment: what is the problem you ran into? can you provide code that caused "when I store an array of objects in the cookies and refresh the browser, the length of the array grows really large" - seems that was the problem ?

Comment: @shershen the code I placed above it what runs when I run my app

Comment: @shershen sorry the initial code Placed there is what is currently working for me, I have edited and added the code that fails

Comment: what do you mean "code that fails" ? you get any error in console? some value is missing?

Comment: @shershen It does not fail per se, only after the cookies array has grown does it start failing because the cookie array is no longer an array

Comment: "cookie array is no longer an array" - then what it becomes? can you output using console.log it every time to see what's the mutation that leads to error.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix the problem is to use the plugin `angular-local-storage`.

It can handle both much more modern LocalStorage/SessionStorage and still have cookies as a fallback - https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

And it has a convenient and configurable API:

```
//set value
localStorageService.set(key, val);
//read value
localStorageService.get(key);
//list all
localStorageService.keys();
```

Comment: Thanks man, but what I really want is to know why $cookies behave in that way, I had already used $cookieStore and it works fine, but $cookies does not